# How can I sort with ransack a column that contains count of the associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have two models: `InStock` and `Variant`:

```
class InStock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :variants
end
```

and :

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :in_stock
end
```

On the in_stocks index page, I have a table with a column: `<%= in_stock.variants.count %>` I want to use `ransack` gem to have a sorting column. For doing this, I have this code in the controller:

```
def index
  @q = InStock.ransack(params[:q])
  @in_stocks = @q.result.includes(:variants)
end
```

and in the view:

```
<th><%= sort_link(@q, :variants_count, t('admin.pages.in_stocks.variants'), default_order: :desc) %></th>
```

But the sorting doesn't work. It doesn't give me any error, just nothing happens. Is there any way to make ransack work with such kind of data? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to `InStock` class

```
ransacker :variants_count do
  query = '(SELECT COUNT(variants.in_stock_id) FROM variants where variants.in_stock_id = in_stocks.id GROUP BY variants.in_stock_id)'
  Arel.sql(query)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Rails [`counter_cache`](https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-start-using-counter-caches-in-rails). Which is what is recommended in [this Ransack issue](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/183)

Which, in your case, adds a `variants_count` column to the `in_stocks` table and a `counter_cache: true` to your `belongs_to` relationship in `Variant`, e.g.:

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :in_stock,
  counter_cache: true
end
```

Using this method, your sort link doesn't even need to change and remains:

```
<th>
  <%= sort_link(@q, :variants_count, t('admin.pages.in_stocks.variants'), default_order: :desc) %>
</th>
```